# Jquery & Ajax script before page load to prevent flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm trying to alter the css values of hidden (display:none) elements on the page BEFORE the page is loaded, although i get unwanted flicker of hidden to unhidden styles (I believe due to script load times).

I'm using jQuery and post in the same function to retrieve information from php about which dom elements require the css change.

Currently all scripts loading at bottom of body, I'm thinking about one of these:

- convert code to pure javascript and stick in header?
- load jQuery and function in header?

I'm poor at pure JS and know that things in header can slow/prevent pageload. Unsure the best practice to go about this, any suggestions?

```
function setHiddenPageBtns()
{
    $.get('php/function/active-user.php?getAcceptedPages=true',

    function(response)
    { 
        var acceptedPages = $.parseJSON(response);

        $.each(acceptedPages, function(key, value)
        {
            $('#'+value+'-btn').css('display','block');
        });            
    });
}
```

EDIT:

I thought the solution would be to ditch jQuery and use async script. I'm using a PURE JS solution so I can load this asynchronusly, but still same problem (on pageload the css style change lags behind and flickers)!

I'm now suspecting is being the server-side taking time to respond to request. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue, im wondering if there is a way to halt the pageload until the css has made changes?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/preload.js" async></script>
```

PRELOAD.JS:

```
function setHiddenBtns()
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'php/function/active-user.php?getAcceptedPages=true', true);

    request.onload = function() 
    {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) 
        {
            var acceptedPages = JSON.parse(request.responseText);;

            for (var i = 0; i < acceptedPages.length; i++) 
            {
                document.getElementById(acceptedPages[i] + '-btn').style.display = "block";
            }
        } 
    };

    request.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this tricky situation I ended up scrapping the javascrip/jquery functions altogether because this flicker was related to the amount of time ajax takes to respond (i think).

Instead 'included' a php function on page that ouputs the $privledge and $acceptlist and inputing the line below inside the html (where the hidden elements style tag would go was a quick fix). This would then display the hidden elements during a pageload with no lag/flicker.

I use this to reveal hidden buttons the user has access to be able to view:

- **'view'** = hidden element name eg('view-btn') stored in assosiative array.
- **$privledge** = string representing user access level to page content used as key to reference array inside acceptList eg('none',view','edit');
- **$acceptList** = assosiative array storing list of privledge arrays storing the element names.

  ```
  <?php if (in_array('view', $acceptList[$privledge]))echo "style='display:block'"?>
  ```

If anyone can think of a neater solution please add a comment/answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<script src="your script" async>
```

at bottom of the body.

In the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) it says:

> If async is present: The script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)

Comment: Nice suggestion, havnt seen async used like this before....still getting a flicker tho cause I have to run the jquery script before. So this will only work with pure js. Looks like im going to have to somehow convert my code...